# How to add read a permission of GCS bucket to a non-engineer member?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I wanna easily get non engineer members to access to data in GCS.
How to handle GCS access permission is described here.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/bucket-level-iam

Do I have to make an IAM in the project, and add his google account to the GCS bucket at the same time?
Is there any way to get him to see data without making IAM for him?

Comment: I guess it works without his IAM in the project, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit the bucket permission for specific user. In your case, you can assign a **Storage Object Viewer** role to a non-engineer member.

Head to your Google Cloud console > Storage > Browser

Select the bucket, choose the permission tab.

Click on the **Add Members** button, key in member's email and select the **Storage Object Viewer** role. They won't need project permissions to browse the informations in the bucket.

After adding the permissions for the member, click on the **Overview** tab and copy the Link URL. The member will be able to see data through this link.

Hope this helps!